# I can't activate features while deploying solutions in SPSD(SharePoint Solution Deployer)

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, solution-deployment, solution

I download the SPSD from CodePlex http://spsd.codeplex.com/, Then I dropped the solution files in solution folder,Then I changed the Defaul.xml for deployment configuration,Then eveything deployed successfully, But feature is not activated while deploying the solution. Pls suggest some idea

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this but I think you should check this file Scripts/CustomTargets.ps1, there is this function

```
function AfterDeploy($vars){
        #   Log "AfterDeploy (Custom Event)" -Type $SPSD.LogTypes.Information -Indent
        #     New-SPSite -Url '$vars["SiteUrl"]' -OwnerAlias '$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME' -Name 'Test Site' -Template 'STS#0'
        #     Install-SPFeature -Path '[feature name]' -Force
        #     Enable-SPFeature -Identity '[feature name]' -Url '$vars["SiteUrl"]' -Force
        #     Enable-SPFeature -Identity [feature guid] -Url '$vars["SiteUrl"]' -Force
        #activate content type association feature in content web application
     }
```

remove the # to un-comment the line.

Comment: I tried that, Then not also it not activated, whether we need to Hardcode the feature id in that?@akbarali